# Create an AlertDialog in a fragment using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In my Android app, I have an observer and in the callback I want to display an AlertDialog. The Builder method however needs a context. I need to obtain the context of the activity that the fragment is in but am not sure how to get it:

```
viewModel.onError.observe(this, Observer {
    val mAlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity) // This needs the activity's context
    mAlertDialog.setMessage(it.toString())
    mAlertDialog.show()
})
```

Comment: use this@YourActivityName

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should pass **`activity!!`** for Fragment.

```
val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity!!)
        dialogBuilder.setMessage(it.toString())
                // if the dialog is cancelable
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
                    dialog, id ->
                    dialog.dismiss()

                })

        val alert = dialogBuilder.create()
        alert.setTitle("Test")
        alert.show()
```

Comment: `requireActivity()` is better

Answer (score 0):

```
viewModel.onError.observe(this, Observer {
    val mAlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@LoginActivity)
    mAlertDialog.setMessage(it.toString())
    mAlertDialog.show()
})
```

Comment: That generates an "unresolved reference" for LoginActivity. onError is running from inside a fragment.

Comment: did u use "LoginActivity" or "YourActivityName"?

Comment: I used LoginActivity. My code is running from a fragment and not in the activity.

Comment: You can create a method and return AlertDialog instance and in observe callback get the object and set message and create and show the dialog.

Comment: For Fragment, just activity should work. or if not, try the method I suggested above by creating a method to get instance of alertdialog

Answer (score -1):

example of when clicking on the button a dialog appears

```
val cancelButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.cancelButton)


cancelButton.setOnClickListener {
AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Confirmation")
    .setMessage("Ara you want to cancel the registration?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes") { dialog, _ -> finish() }
    .setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }
    .create()
    .show()
```

}

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**